# Ruby: extract all members of an object

Tags: ruby, syntax

How do I extract all members (methods, variables, constants, objects, etc) of an arbitrary object and pass them to a block?

```
def inside(obj)
  #pass all the members of the object to the block
end

inside myLink do
  url = "myurl.com"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use instance_eval:

```
def inside obj, &block
  obj.instance_eval &block
end
```

You'll still need to use self though:

```
inside myLink do
   self.url = "myurl.com"
   # or:
   @url = "myurl.com"
end
```

Comment: Hmm I still wonder if it is possible to enable the syntax I proposed in my OP.

Comment: Not in Ruby, the code in your OP would create a local variable called "url" and assign "myurl.com" to it. It would not affect the instance variable @url of the object passed in.